# Generating web-consumable map tiles from ECRG raster data using ArcGIS Pro

Tags: arcgis-desktop, leaflet, arcgis-pro, tiles, ecrg

I have been tasked with transforming ECRG raster data from the National Geospatial Agency into something that can be consumed by Leaflet, or other web mapping libraries.  I am able to load the raster data into ArcGIS Pro to poke around at it, but my ArcGIS Pro skills are not as strong as I'd like.

Is there a way, using ArcGIS Pro, to generate a series of slippymap tiles from ECRG raster data, that we can host on our own tile server?  The goal is to end up with tile names organized in folders, as described in the osm wiki[Slippy map tilenames](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Slippy_map_tilenames).

I have tried a number of things in ArcGIS Pro, like creating a [map tile package](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/tool-reference/data-management/create-map-tile-package.htm), which generates an lpkx file, but that's not what I need.  I've dug around a number of their geoprocessing tools.  The closest tool I can find to what I'm looking for is the "Share as a web layer" tool, which looks like this

[image]

As you can see, it asks for the zoom levels for which I want to create tiles, the image format, and gives an estimate on the number of tiles (and total size) that will be generated.  This is close to what I am looking for but there is no option here to generate the tiles to a local directory - they seem to only offer the option to upload to ArcGIS Online.  I need a hard copy of these files locally, as the data is classified and will be served within a closed system.

### Edit - Getting closer

I loosely followed @Graeme's answer with generating a tile cacheing scheme:

[image]

And then I was able to use the [Export Tile Cache](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/tool-reference/data-management/export-tile-cache.htm) tool to export these to actual tile PNG images.

[image]

I am fairly confused about the naming scheme used.  The first level, I beleive, are zooom levels:

[image]

Wiithin each of these folders, I get more directories (as hoped for), but named with R0000XXa type naming convention

[image]

Initially I thought that perhaps each one means "row", as in the x dimension, as expect from the z/x/y slippymap convention, but I'm confused about the letter suffix.  Then in each folder, finally, the images, correctly broken up into 256x256 pngs:

[image]

Though as you see, these are now arranged in rows, as opposed to columns, as you would expect from a z/x/y scheme.  I again am confused by the naming convention, with the a/b/c/d/e/f sufffixes.

Comment: If you are seeking "other options as far as transforming this data for leaflet consumption as well" then there is the [softwarerecs.se] Stack Exchange that provides software recommendations.

Comment: I'm not really seeking other software specifically, as I think ArcGIS Pro is the primary tool to do what I'm trying to do, which is what this question is primarily about. But I'm certain open to suggestions for other methods to do it as well, if anyone sees the question and says "there are better ways to do this"

Comment: Our volunteers are always welcome to propose alternative ideas in their answers but to keep questions focused they should not be asked for.  Doing that turns a focused question into one that is open-ended and discussion generating.

Answer (score 3):

It's not clear how you are planning to serve the tiles. Anyhow, to generate a tile cache in ArcGIS Pro you first design the tiling cache using Generate Tile Cache Tiling Scheme, you are potentially chasing Exploded storage format (if you aren't using ArcGIS Server/Online) https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/tool-reference/data-management/generate-tile-cache-tiling-scheme.htm and then to create the tiles you use Manage Tile Cache https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/tool-reference/data-management/manage-tile-cache.htm

Make sure you have enough storage space before you start, if you are covering large areas at a range of scales this process can take many hours or days. Suggest you do a test scheme first with limited scales and coverage and get the entire process working on your server.

Comment: This is definitely pushing me in the right direction.  I was able to generate 256x256 png tiles from my raster, but the naming convention is not what I expected.  I edited my question to better explain how I plan to serve the tiles (which also explains how I need them to be organized when creating them), and I added some info about what I did to get my result, and why its a bit off from what I need.  Please take a look and LMK if you have any ideas for me, thank you for your guidance

Comment: I do not know how to convert the ArcGIS tiles to xyz naming convention. I think given you need xyz tiles for Leaflet I think it might be quicker and easier to use QGIS that has a built-in tool Generate XYZ Tiles (directory) looks pretty simple, quick Google search and this tutorial comes up https://www.orrbodies.com/tutorial/generating-tiles-qgis/

Comment: Amazing suggestion, thank you.  I wasn't sure if QGIS could handle ECRG data, but Its worth a shot  I will try this and report back when I get a chance

Comment: Well, that worked like a champ, *exactly* what I needed.  If you edit your answer to include this comment about QQGIS, I can mark it as the answer.  Thank you!!!